# redirect flash attribute not working for List<>

Tags: java, spring, redirect

I would like to redirect a message list from a post to a get.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/ManageNonRoutedActivities")
public ModelAndView manageNonRoutedActivities(ModelAndView modelAndView,
                                              ArrayList<Message> messages,
                                              @ModelAttribute("nonRoutedActivity") NonRoutedActivity nonRoutedActivity,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "search", defaultValue = "") String search,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "orderField", defaultValue = "Description") String orderByField,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "orderDirection", defaultValue = "asc") String orderByDirection) {

    ManageNonRoutedActivitiesRequest request = new ManageNonRoutedActivitiesRequest(new ManageNonRoutedActivitiesDAOImpl(), search, orderByField, orderByDirection);

    System.out.println(messages.size());

    modelAndView.setViewName("default");
    modelAndView.addObject("viewModel", new ManageNonRoutedActivitiesImpl(request, search, orderByField, messages));
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/ManageNonRoutedActivities")
public String updateOrCreateActivity(@Valid NonRoutedActivity nonRoutedActivity,
                                     BindingResult result,
                                     RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    SecurityAccessor securityAccessor = new SecurityAccessor();
    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return manageErrorsForManageNonRoutedActivities(result, nonRoutedActivity, redirectAttributes, messages);
    }

    if (nonRoutedActivity.shouldUpdateEndDate()) {
        nonRoutedActivity.updateEndDate();
        messages.add(new Message("endDate.add.success", "success"));
    } else
        messages.add(new Message("activity.add.success", "success"));

    nonRoutedActivity.setModifiedBy(securityAccessor.getLoggedInUsersName());
    nonRoutedActivity.save();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messages", messages);
    return "redirect:/ManageNonRoutedActivities";
}
```

The problem I'm having is that messages in the get part of the controller keeps coming out null. I originally had this `messages` instance as a `List<Message>` but this did not work since `messages` can be null. This caused an issue since `List` cannot be instanciated. This is why I am using `ArrayList`. This is not working though because the `ArrayList` is not binding correctly. Anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve this issue without creating a wrapper for the list?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure this is the best solution but the if I remove the name of the redirect attribute it works.